# How to get Selected element in bootstrap dropdown, where dropdown is dynamically populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

This is similar to
[How to Display Selected Item in Bootstrap Button Dropdown Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437446/how-to-display-selected-item-in-bootstrap-button-dropdown-title)

Only difference, my dropdown list is not static and it is populated through ajax response.
Below code **doesn't work only for** `<li>` items which are populated dynamically.

To test above, I intentionally put a static `<li>` when I click on that item, I can see success message in console. But, when I click on `<li>` which are appended dynamically, I don't get anything in console.

I believe, there is some jQuery fundamental knowledge I missing here. jQuery gurus, comments/thoughts?

Here is some code for further clarification.

Java Script Code:

Printing selected option in console

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
        console.log("Selected Option:"+$(this).text());
});
```

Populating dropdown from ajax JSON response

```
$.each(response, function (key, value) {
    $("#dropDownUL").append("<li> <a tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"#\" align=\"left\"> " + value + "</a> </li>");
})
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="dropdown btn">
    <div id="dropDownId" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
        Collections
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </div>           
    <ul id="dropDownUL"  class="dropdown-menu pull-left" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" align="left">Static test Option</a></li>
    </ul>


</div>
```

So, once again, if I click on `Static test Option` I can see message in console : `Selected Option: Static test Option`

But, when I click on `Option2` `Option 3` which is populated from ajax response, I don't see anything in console.

Let me know if something is not clear. I will try to explain further.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function () {
    console.log("Selected Option:"+$(this).text());
});
```

This is just simple event delegation...Elements that don't exist at page load must have the event delegated to a static parent element that **does** exist at page load.

We leverage jQuery's .on() to complete this.

```
  $(staticElement).on(event, dynamicElement, function(){ //etc });
```

**Obligatory Edit**

Please don't actually bind elements to the `$(document)` and instead choose the closest parent element that is static. This is for performance reasons.