# bootstrap amazon style search bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, searchbar

Is there an easy way to do something similar to this in bootstrap? A search bar with a drop down selector for a different category? I've been looking through their documentation, something similar to [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) but with the dropdown being attached to the search bar is what I'm looking for. I want it to be part of my navbar. I recall seeing an example online but can't seem to find it now. Also wondering where it would go in relation to my header at the moment

[image]

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-left">
              <li><%= link_to 'New Review', 
              if (current_user) 
                new_review_path 
              else
                log_in_path
              end %></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Home",    '/' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
              <% if current_user %>
                <li><%= link_to "Log out", log_out_path %>
              <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign up", sign_up_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Log in", log_in_path %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: [Input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns) + [Display Selected Item in Bootstrap Button Dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061812/display-selected-item-in-bootstrap-button-dropdown-title-place-holder-text)

Comment: Here's something: http://w3lessons.info/2013/08/08/amazon-style-search-box-using-jquery-css/

Comment: segmented buttons, that was it

Answer (score 9):

Please, refer this it satisfied your requirement
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#contains">Contains</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than ></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#less_than">Less than < </a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#all">Anything</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
        var concept = $(this).text();
        $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
        $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
    });
});
```

Refer this link
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/search-panel-with-filters

Comment: this worked amazingly for me.  just a little bit of a change from the OOB bootstrap dropdown component.  very nice!

Answer (score 1):

See if this example that helps you..

javascript:

```
/* activate scrollspy menu */
$('body').scrollspy({
  target: '#navbar-collapsible',
  offset: 50
});

/* smooth scrolling sections */
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
/*
A custom Bootstrap 3.1 template
from http://bootply.com

This CSS code should follow the 'bootstrap.css'
in your HTML file.

license: MIT
author: bootply.com
*/

html,body {
    height:100%;
    background:center no-repeat fixed url('/assets/example/bg_suburb.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.icon-bar {
    background-color:#fff;
}

.navbar-trans {
    background-color:#279ddd;
    color:#fff;
}

.navbar-trans li>a:hover,.navbar-trans li>a:focus,.navbar-trans li.active {
    background-color:#38afef;
}

.navbar-trans a{
    color:#fefefe;
}

.navbar-trans .form-control:focus {
    border-color: #eee;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(100,100,100,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(100,100,100,0.6);
}

section {
    padding-top:70px;  
    padding-bottom:50px; 
    min-height:calc(100% - 1px);
}

.v-center {
    padding-top:10%;
    font-size:70px;
}

.well {
    border-color:transparent;
}

a.list-group-item.active,[class*='-info'] {
    background-color: #168ccc;
    color:#fff;
}

#section1 {
    background-color: #168ccc;
    color:#dedeff;
}

#section2 {
    background-color: #e5e5ef;
    color:#686868;
}

#section3 {
    background-color: #168ccc;
    color:#ddd;
}

#section4 {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#444;
}

#section5,#section7,#section7 a {
    color:#f5f5f5;
}

#section6 {
    background-color: #168ccc;
    color:#ddd;
}

footer {
    background-color:#494949;
    color:#ddd;
    min-height:100px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}

footer .nav>li>a {
    padding:3px;
    color:#ccc;
}

footer .nav>li>a:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:#fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-trans navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapsible">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#section1">What</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">When</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">How</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section5">Five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section6">Why</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section7">Who</a></li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
          <div class="input-group"> 
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li> 
              </ul>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What are searching for?">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section class="container-fluid" id="section1">
    <h1 class="text-center v-center">Sectionalize.</h1>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 text-center"><h3>Robust</h3><p>There is other content and snippets of details or features that can be placed here..</p><i class="fa fa-cog fa-5x"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center"><h3>Simple</h3><p>You may also want to create content that compells users to scroll down more..</p><i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-10 text-center"><h3>Clean</h3><p>In the first 30 seconds of a user's visit to your site they decide if they're going to stay..</p><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-5x"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div><!--/row-->
    <div class="row"><br></div>
  </div><!--/container-->
</section>

<section class="container-fluid" id="section2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
        <h1>What is Bootstrap?</h1>
        <br>
        <p class="lead">Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating websites and web applications. It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions. It is the No.1 project on GitHub with 65,000+ stars and 23,800 forks (as of March 2014) [1] and has been used by NASA and MSNBC, among many others..</p>
        <br> 
        <i style="font-size:120px" class="fa fa-camera fa-5x"></i>
        <p>Big 'ol Camera Icon</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="container-fluid" id="section3">
    <h1 class="text-center">Bootstrap is Responsive</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <h3 class="text-center">Vertical scrolling has become a popular and lasting trend in Web design.</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">Some brand-tacular designs even have home page content that is taller that 12,000 pixels. That's a lotta content.</div>
          <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">Anyhoo, this is just some random blurb of text, and Bootply.com is a playground and code editor for Bootstrap.</div>
        </div>
        <p class="text-center">
          <img src="/assets/example/img_mtnpeople.png" class="img-responsive center-block ">
        </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>

<section class="container-fluid" id="section4">
    <h2 class="text-center">Change this Content. Change the world.</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
      <img src="/assets/example/bg_smartphones.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block ">
      <p class="text-center">Images will scale down proportionately as browser width narrows.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container-fluid" id="section5">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="list-group">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                <h2 class="list-group-item-heading">Basic</h2>
                <h6>Free to get started</h6>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 100 - more about this</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 2 - this is more about this</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 3 GB</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 4</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Feature</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Feature</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Get Started</button>
              </a>
            </div>
      </div><!--/left-->

      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="list-group text-center">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                <h2 class="list-group-item-heading">Better</h2>
                <h6>Most popular plan</h6>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 200 - more about this</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 2 - this is more about this</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 5 GB</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 6</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Feature</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Feature</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">$10 per month</button>
              </a>
            </div>
      </div><!--/middle-->

      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="list-group text-right">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
                <h2 class="list-group-item-heading">Best</h2>
                <h6>For enterprise grade</h6>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 100 - more about this</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 2 - this is more about this</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 8 GB</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Option 10</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Unlimited</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Unlimited</p>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">$20 per month</button>
              </a>
            </div>
      </div><!--/right-->

    </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/container--> 
  </div>
</section>

<section class="container-fluid" id="section6">
    <h2 class="text-center">Do you see what I mean?</h2>
    <p class="text-center lead">Add some compelling information here</p>
    <img src="/assets/example/bg_iphone.png" class="img-responsive center-block ">

</section>

<section class="container" id="section7">
    <h1 class="text-center">Social Media Fascination</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <!--fontawesome icons-->
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-4 text-center">
       <i class="fa fa-github fa-4x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-4 text-center">
       <i class="fa fa-foursquare fa-4x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-4 text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-4x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-4 text-center">
       <i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-4x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-4 text-center">
       <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-4x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-4 text-center">
       <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-4 text-center">
       <i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-4x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-4 text-center">
       <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x"></i>
      </div>
  </div><!--/row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <br><br>
      <p>
        <a href="http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/sectionalize">Get the code for this template.</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<footer id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 column">          
          <h4>Information</h4>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="about-us.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.html">Benefits</a></li>
            <li><a href="elements.html">Developers</a></li>
          </ul> 
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 column">          
          <h4>Follow Us</h4>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pinterest</a></li>
          </ul> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 column">          
          <h4>Contact Us</h4>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Headquarters</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
          </ul> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 column">          
          <h4>Customer Service</h4>
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Delivery Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
          </ul> 
      </div>
    </div><!--/row-->
  </div>
</footer>
```

http://bootply.com/129806

This is a full-width search form in the navbar along with an `input-group-btn` on the left side of the input that is used as a dropdown of categories.