# Bootstrap multiple dropdown menus change corresponding button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with multiple dropdowns like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Please Select From List</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Item I</a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Item II</a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Item III</a></li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
   <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Other</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I want to change the button text to selected element value. I've found this thread: [How to Display Selected Item in Bootstrap Button Dropdown Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437446/how-to-display-selected-item-in-bootstrap-button-dropdown-title), which explains how to retrieve the text/value of selected item and change the text of the button, but there's a problem when there's more drop down menus on the page, the below script changes labels for all buttons present on the page:

```
$(function(){    
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){    
      $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
      $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
   });  
});
```

How to modify it so that it would only change the corresponding dropdown menu button?
As a side question: is there really no simple way of having `<select>` like behavior with dropdown menus out of the box in bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add specificity to your jQuery selector. Currently, you're selecting **all** elements with a .btn class that are the first child of their parent. What you want to do instead is get the current element's parent `.btn-group` then find the `.btn:first-child` inside of that. You can do that as follows:

```
$(function(){    
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){    
        $(this).closest('.btn-group').find(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
        $(this).closest('.btn-group').find(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
    });  
});
```

Comment: a fiddle would be more batter

Answer (score 1):

One of many potential solutions, transverse up the DOM to find the group it's in, and then target the button within the group.

```
$(function(){    
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){ 
      var target = $(this).closest('.btn-group').find('.btn:first-child')
      target.text($(this).text());
      target.val($(this).text());
   });  
});
```

Comment: a fiddle would be more batter