# how to display selected value as coma separator in button in bootstrap multi select drop down?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using jquery multi-select drop down in my project. I have a drop down with maximum 4 value and if I select a value from the drop-down it is displaying as '3 selected', '4 selected' as bellow image, but I want to display all selected value as coma separate instead of '4 selected'. I am using `/bootstrap-multiselect.js`

[image]

I am generating dropdown dynamically as bellow html code,

```
                @if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                int i = 1;
                foreach (DataRow categogyItem in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {


   <div class="ibvm subhselectfildwrap">

                                <select class="listbox selectpicker" id=@string.Format("ddlEmail{0}", i) multiple="multiple" name="@string.Format("Email{0}", i)" style="width: 500px !important;">

                                    @if (ds.Tables.Count > 2)
                                    {
                                        foreach (DataRow EmailItem in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
                                        {

                                            if (NC.ToInt(EmailItem["IN00_01_InBoxId"]) == NC.ToInt(categogyItem["InBoxId"]))
                                            {
                                                <option value="@EmailItem["IN00_01_DetailID"]">@EmailItem["IN00_01_EmailId"]</option>

                                            }

                                        }
                                    }

                                </select>

                            </div>

                                    i++;
                }
            }
```

in the js file, I have created code as bellow, when I check this code while putting `Debugger` in js it's working properly and button text has been changed with selected coma separator value but after then js has been called and value has been changed as '4 selected'.

I have referred [sample question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437446/how-to-display-selected-item-in-bootstrap-button-dropdown-title) also. but I can not able to find the solution.

```
        $('.selectpicker').multiselect({
        enableFiltering: false,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        selectAllJustVisible: false,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        buttonWidth: '100%'
    });

    $("select").change(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + ", ";
        });

        $(this).parent('.subhselectfildwrap').find('div.btn-group').find('span.multiselect-selected-text').text(str);

    })
  .trigger("change");
```

**Edit:**

I am using 'http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js'

Comment: Which multi-select jquery plugin your using, can you add link of that?

Comment: bootstrap-multiselect.js default no of option displaying is 3, after the 3 values selected it shows 4 selected and so on http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-numberDisplayed.

Comment: @AmitKumar i have edit quetion and added the link of the js i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As It is default behavior to bootstrap multi select dropdown, So if you need to show all label instead of count, then you need to modify buttontext.

Here I have updated the button text on every change event.
HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="test" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
            <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="onions">Onions</option>
            <option value="mozarella1">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms1">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="2pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="3onions">Onions</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('#test').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    maxHeight: 150,
    buttonWidth: 'auto',
    numberDisplayed: 2,
    nSelectedText: 'selected',
    nonSelectedText: 'None selected',
    buttonText: function(options, select) {
        var numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;
        if (options.length === 0) {
            return this.nonSelectedText + '';
        } else {
            var selected = '';
            options.each(function() {
                var label = ($(this).attr('label') !== undefined) ?
                    $(this).attr('label') : $(this).html();
                selected += label + ', ';
            });
            return selected.substr(0, selected.length - 2) + '';

        }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
 .btn-block {width : auto !important;}
```

Here You also need to set buttontext width property `auto`

[**JSFiddle Method 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/66yrxfyb/2/)

**Another way to achieve this.**

- Get total option count.
- Get all option text.
- Then use plugin configuration property.

Js Code

```
var total = $('#test option').length;
var options = $('#test option');

var allText = $.map(options ,function(option) {
    return option.value;
}).join(',');

$('#test').multiselect({numberDisplayed: total,allSelectedText : allText});
```

**[JsFiddle Method 2](https://jsfiddle.net/qzLtycfc/)**